# How to get the height of an image from a url in android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to get the height of an image from a url in android, I have been able to find many examples of this in java but unfortunately it requires importing java classes such as awt and swing which I am finding out I cannot use with an android project, does anyone know a way by which this can be done in android?

Comment: first create drawable or bitmap from url and after it you can get height of that drawable or bitmap..

Comment: swing and awt tags removed -- they have nothing to do with the actual question itself or its ultimate answer.